# Show Notification after certain Duration - toastr.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, toastr

I have a list of Messages I need to show to the User, which are loaded using Ajax after certain periods of time in `data.NotificationDtos`

The thing is that I have to show one Message at a time for a certain amount of time say 10 seconds,

At the moment it is displaying all notifications at once.

So I need my steps to be:

1. After Ajax Request toastr first Message with
   `toastr.info(val.DetailedMessage, val.EventMessage);`
2. Then Show Above Toastr Message for certain time.
3. Then continue with other Messages until all are complete.

But I come around how to do that.

```
function loadNotifications() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNotifications", "Users")',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                   
                $.each(data.NotificationDtos, function (i, val) {
                    toastr.info(val.DetailedMessage, val.EventMessage);
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rudimentary implementation could use [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout):

```
var messages = ["Hello", "World", "Including", "Antartica"]; 

function showMessages(messages, interval){
    // Loop through messages
    for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
        // Create timer for each message
        window.setTimeout((function(){
            var message = messages[i];
            return function(){
                toastr.info(message);
            }
        })(), i*interval*1000);
    }
}

// Show the list of messages, separate them by 3 seconds apiece
showMessages(messages, 3);
```

Proof of concept: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khkav6va/).